# Formula to count members in a list with Google Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, count, formula, google-docs

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a set of data that looks like this:

```
 A  | B             | C  | D
--------------------------------
 .. | John Smith    | .. | 2011
 .. | john smith    | .. | 2011
 .. | Kathy Ericson | .. | 2012
 .. | JOHN SMITH    | .. | 2013
 .. | Kathy Ericson | .. | 2012
```

What I would like to do is count each unique person (John Smith/john smith, 2011 is NOT the same as JOHN SMITH, 2013) and display in column E how often that person shows up in the list. In this example:

```
 A  | B             | C  | D    | E
--------------------------------------
 .. | John Smith    | .. | 2011 | 2
 .. | john smith    | .. | 2011 | 2
 .. | Kathy Ericson | .. | 2012 | 2
 .. | JOHN SMITH    | .. | 2013 | 1
 .. | Kathy Ericson | .. | 2012 | 2
```

How would I go about creating a formula that could do that? I have basic knowledge of Excel formulas, so perhaps a VLOOKUP?

Comment: Should names be treated as case-insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking the `SUM` of the `UNIQUE` rows in your array?

In the documentation for that function, it says

> Returns only the unique rows in the source array, discarding
>   duplicates. The rows are returned according to the order in which they
>   first appear in the source array.
>
> ...
>
> - =Unique(A1:B10) returns all of the unique rows from A1:B10.

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=table.cs&topic=25273

Comment: I didn't even think about getting only the unique rows! That will make the data a lot easier to look through. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula on Google Spreadsheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*($B$2:$B$6=B2)*($C$2:$C$6=C2)))
```

See [this example online](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avv4SM5QSNYtdHlUU3E0REFMMVdjVFpQeUkwOVVZRWc&hl=en_GB)